# How to make a model parameter unique by a other parameter in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want my `id` field to be unique per each `customer` field. Just like the option `unique_for_date` from Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#unique) but in this case, not date but customer.

```
class Sample(NGObject):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=False)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name="blood_samples", on_delete=models.SET(get_default_customer))
```

I believe this should be done, before the `save()` method?

When a User writes the wrong ID (that already exists) I would also like to present the information in the Admin Form just like it would for normal unique error.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Meta:
        unique_together = ('sample_id', 'customer',)
```

This has done the trick :)